# Movie with dystopian future where water had become precious and guarded by killing devices

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a SF movie in 2010. It was about a dystopian future where water had become so precious it was guarded by remotely-controlled killing devices. A young man stole some water, in Mexico (the country, not the town), and the US employee (maybe soldier) operating the drones made a mistake and bombed the young man's house, killing his father instead of killing this young man.

The rest of the movie is the story of these two men, the soldier and the young man, questioning their world and looking for each other.

I remember thinking it was a very good SF movie and I would like to know the title, so I can watch it again. I watched it in English. It might have been Mexican SF but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*Sleep Dealer*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0804529/?ref_=ttpl_ov) (2008).

> The near future. Like tomorrow. In a world marked by closed borders, corporate warriors, and a global computer network, three strangers risk their lives to connect, break through the barriers of technology, and unseal their fates.

This synopsis mentions the water and the drones.

> Memo (Luis Fernando Peña), a young Mexican, lives on a milpa in Santa
> Ana, Oaxaca with his family. Once, a river flowed through the milpa,
> which his father owns. But a few years ago, the Del Rio Water Company
> built a dam upstream. Now, residents of Santa Ana must pay $1/gallon
> to enter the facility and collect water.
>
> In his spare time, Memo tinkers with discarded radio parts and builds
> an antenna to pick up voices from far away. One night, he overhears a
> transmission between Rudy (Jacob Vargas), a drone gunship operator,
> and his compatriots. His signal is detected, and tracked down to his
> family's shack in Santa Ana. Live on TV the next day, Rudy carries out
> a mission to neutralize an "aqua-terrorist intercept". As Memo and
> family watch on their TV, they soon realize that the target is the
> antenna on top of their shack. They run back to the shack, only to see
> it obliterated by a hovering drone gunship. As Memo's father crawls
> out of the building, Rudy gets confirmation that he is a known
> "aqua-terrorist", and Rudy fires a rocket at him, blowing him to bits.